# How to assign a particular row of two dimensional array passed as an argument of the function to one-dimensional vector in c++

Tags: arrays, vector, row, assign, dimensional

This is what I do, but I get segmentation fault when I debug (Step Into -> v.assign() is the problem.

```
void vertex::sort_all_neighbours(int i, int **array, int size_array){

v.reserve(size_array);    
v.assign(&array[i][0], &array[i][size_array-1]);
//for (j = 0; j < size_array; j++) v[j] = array[i][j];
make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
sort_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(v.begin());
assign_neighbors(i);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I probably change something in other functions/procedures this is a solution

```
void vertex::sort_all_neighbours(int i, int **array, int size_array){

v.reserve(size_array);    
v.assign(&array[i][0], &array[i][size_array]);
make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
sort_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(v.begin());
assign_neighbors(i);
}
```